# Is there a way to select elements that use a specific CSS3 property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to select all of the elements in the DOM that have a border-radius !== 0.

Do you guys know a way of doing that?

Comment: without assigning them a specific class? That won't be efficient...

Comment: What about vendor-prefixed border radius support? Eg `-moz-border-radius`, `webkit-border-radius`, `-o-border-radius`, etc? EG the case where `css('border-radius')` returns nothing but `css('-webkit-border-radius')` returns something?

Comment: @RoatinMarth The [1.8 version of jQuery](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) addresses this with automatic CSS prefixing in the `.css()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function.

```
$(elements).filter(function(){
     return parseInt($(this).css("border-radius"),10) != 0;
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `parseInt($(this).css("border-radius"),10)` before comparing it?

Comment: Now we just need to deal with the rare but possible case where `border-radius: 0px 2px`....

Answer (score 4):

Use a CSS class to define your border radius, then use jQuery to select them.

CSS:

```
.border-radius {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.border-radius')
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP wanted, but still better than not changing HTML in terms of performance. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Because I like to be thorough, we ought to consider the fact that `border-radius` can accept multiple values to describe all four corners individually:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    var br = $(this).css("border-radius").split(' '),
        test = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = br.length; i < j; i++) {
        test = test || parseInt(br[i], 10);
    };
    return test;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/SLUcb/

That said, filtering EVERY element on the page is outrageously inefficient. The better approach is just to assign the `border-radius` to a class and test for the existence of objects with that class.